# how to step through the http modules and static code during debugging without any breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, debugging

I am using C# and Visual Studio 2010 for an ASP.NET MVC2 Application. I would like to trace each and every request in my application, like which modules are called and which static classes and their corresponding code gets executed. Without setting breakpoints, i cannot do these now.

Is there any tool or workaround for this situation. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try PostSharp as well as ANTS profiler. If you want LOGGING - then PostSharp is the way to go.